# Returning results from every "user" grouped for pagnation of dompdf

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, dompdf

I have two tables in mysql.

people is an identification table of users.. names/etc

trans is a transaction table, what the users have done (add/subtract balances)

I am wanting to return every "ident" from people, then search trans for that ident's matching rows, and then after all are returned, echo the page break, so each person gets their own page print out.  (there shouldn't be so many transactions that a page is not enough..)  Also to subquery the balance remaining (trans has both credits and debits, could be positive or negative).

Structure:

```
people.id #(not queried, unique/auto-increment)
people.name
people.location
people.ident #(assigned number that is same as trans.ident)

trans.id #(not queried, unique/auto-inc)
trans.date
trans.ident
trans.amount
trans.description
```

Queries:

```
$query = "SELECT people.ident, people.name, people.location, trans.ident, trans.date, trans.amount, trans.description FROM people LEFT JOIN trans ON people.ident = trans.ident";
$balance = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM trans WHERE ident = $ident", $dblink), 0);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Echo results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['ident']. " - ". $row['amount']. " - " .row['description']; 
    echo('<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>'); 
    }
```

This will print out each transaction, and they are sorted by the ident, but with div after each... 
I would like to print out the name and location, also their remaining balance ( once on a div.. and then trans under like so:

```
<div class="user">['name']  ['location'] $balance</div>  #These aren't rows, just a single return
<div class="trans">$row['amount']. " - ". $row['description'];</div>
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Where is the output code for `<div class="user">` and `<div class="trans">`?

Comment: Further down in a php echo on an html generated page for dompdf to pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is going to be a *little bit difficult* because you can not always be sure that the name/location for a person inside the people table is actually for the same person/location. Your database is not completely normalised.

That being said, you can do what you want with a few small changes to your query and some PHP code :)

```
 $query = "SELECT people.ident, people.name, people.location,
           trans.ident, trans.date, trans.amount, trans.description
           FROM people LEFT JOIN trans ON people.ident = trans.ident
           ORDER BY peeople.name, people.location, trans.ident";
```

Echo results:

```
$lastName = null;
$lastLocation = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if (($lastName !== $row['name']) or ($lastLocation != $row['location'])) {
         echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['ident']. " - ". $row['amount']. " - " .row['description'];
         $lastName= $row['name'];
         $lastLocation = $row['location'];
    }

    /* ... output the transaction  line ... */
    echo('<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>'); 
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to sort by location at all, just name, so removed them and added else for the trans list.. and put the echo page break on first line of the if, otherwise it still puts it on each line.  It creates a page break to start, but that works well with a title page.  Also put a subquery in on that if, to calculate balance, not ideal but works.